# Any way to enforce Windows 7 to run 32-bit sidebar.exe?

Tags: windows-7, desktop-gadget, sidebar, 32-vs-64-bit

Is there any way to enforce Windows 7 to run 32-bit `sidebar.exe` instead of 64-bit?

Comment: Why?, do you have some gadgets that are only 32bit?

Comment: Not that anyone has to explain or justify any question they ever ask on any stack exchange site ever - but i am curious why.

Comment: When we needed this to happen it was because one of our gadgets had a Silverlight control in it, and Silverlight (pre version 5) is 32 bit only

Comment: Counter to this question, I would rather find out how to force the *64-bit* version to run. I just noticed that on a 64-bit laptop, the 32-bit version of the sidebar is running instead of the 64-bit version. I can’t recall how it was set to autorun, but I don’t think it was by manually adding the startup entry; it was probably through an official mechanism like an *autorun* check-box or something. Curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regedit to edit the following registry key:

```
\\HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
Item name : SideBar
```

and change the value of `SideBar` to this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Sidebar\sidebar.exe" /autoRun
```

(The only change is loading sidebar.exe from `c:\program files (x86)\`instead of `c:\program files\`)